# what event triggered when a page themes changed

Tags: asp.net

Hi all what event triggered when a page themes changed at dynamically?  i faced this question in an interview..

ex: In orkut when we press the themes link/button we can get what we wanted..

thanks saj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Microgen's comment here is a [link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/HTML/ThemeChanging.aspx) for you to see a solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is no event specific for changing the page theme because the theme can only be changed inside the Page's PreInit event.